# android application exist after location switch on

Tags: android, android-permissions

I need to use Location in my application and I check location at every onResume. When location is switched off I try to switch  it on with:

```
val lm = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager 
if (!LocationManagerCompat.isLocationEnabled(lm)) {
            val intent = Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(intent)          
            return
        }
```

When this activity finished my application exited. I tried startActivityForResult, but it didn't help. How can I return to my application after settings?

thx
Zamek

Comment: please post your activity code. If user is clicking back button ideally it should comeback to your app if there is no custom behavior specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
  override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    checkLocation()
  }
  
   private fun checkLocation() {
    val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        .addLocationRequest(LocationRequest().apply {
            interval = 10000
            fastestInterval=5000
            priority=LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER
        })
    val settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this)

    val task : Task<LocationSettingsResponse> = settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
    task.addOnSuccessListener {
        model.start()
    }
    task.addOnFailureListener{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION), REQUEST_LOCATION)
    }
 }

 override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray) {

    when(requestCode) {
        
        REQUEST_LOCATION -> locationResult(grantResults)
 
    }
}

private fun locationResult(grantResults: IntArray) {
    if (grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        val lm = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        if (!LocationManagerCompat.isLocationEnabled(lm)) {
            val intent = Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(intent)
            return
        }
        model.start()
        return
    }
    exitApplication()
}
```

I checked it on a Xiaomi device. Maybe that should be the problem...

thx,
Zamek